Historical snapshots starting from genesis?
One of the implemented SIMDs (https://docs.solanalabs.com/implemented-proposals/rpc-transaction-history) mentions uploading long-term transactions history to the Google BigTable. Are there publicly available BigTable instances with this data? Are there projects or teams using this feature to store the information since the genesis?
Does BigQuery public dataset (https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/bigquery-public-data/crypto-solana-mainnet-us?project=ardent-girder-403621) contain data from the genesis?
Also, there is info that Anza uses Google bucket to store historical snapshots. Is there any information on how this data can be accessed?

If you access the public RPC nodes at https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com, the getBlock / getSignaturesForAddress / getTransaction endpoints are backed by Google BigTable. And it has information going all the way back to genesis.
As for the historical snapshot data, I'm not familiar with what you're referencing.
